# PNG decode from memory with lodepng on Android

Tags: c, png, sdl, lodepng

I'm using "lodepng.h" library with SDL (RWOps) to decode png files from my Android device and I cannot seem to figure out the correct way to call lodepng and decode the PNG from memory. The version of SDL is 3.0.

First, I use SDL's RWops to open the file on Android (path looks good):

```c
// get path on Android device, then open it and return the data
char *load_binary_file_on_android(const char *path) {
const char *full_android_path = get_path_on_android(path);
SDL_Log("Android path: %s\n", full_android_path);
char *data;

// Open binary file
SDL_RWops *io = SDL_RWFromFile(full_android_path, "rb");
if (io != NULL) {
    size_t data_size = (size_t) SDL_RWsize(io);
    data = (char *) SDL_malloc(data_size + 1);
    if (SDL_RWread(io, data, data_size) != data_size) {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_ERROR,
                     "SDL_RWread failed: %s\n",
                     SDL_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Log("Reading file %s\n%08b\n", full_android_path, data);
    SDL_RWclose(io);
} else {
    SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_ERROR, "SDL_RWops failed: %s", SDL_GetError());
}

SDL_free(full_android_path);

return data;
}
```

Next, I use "lodepng" to decode the raw pixel data:

```c
const unsigned char *raw_pixel_data = load_binary_file_on_android(file_name);
unsigned char *data;
unsigned int width, height;
unsigned int error = lodepng_decode32(&data, &width, &height,
                                      &raw_pixel_data, sizeof(unsigned char));
```

The error returned is `lodepng_decode32 failed loading textures/texture.png with error 27: PNG file is smaller than a PNG header` ... My gut tells me I'm casting the data format or not pulling all the data. The data format should be `unsigned char` in an 32bit (RGBA) PNG file where each color is 8 bits (not sure if I said that correctly...).

I've tried modifying the `sizeof()` and logging the raw pixel data but I still keep getting the same error (Error 27).

Comment: [Example 2](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng/blob/master/examples/example_decode.c#L56) may help.

Comment: You need to pass the value assigned to `data_size` in `load_binary_file_on_android` as the last parameter to `lodepng_decode32`. A way to do that would be to pass a pointer to a `size_t` to the load function and assign the value inside it.

Comment: You should  also pass `raw_pixel_data` and not `&raw_pixel_data` to the decode function.

Comment: Thanks - I passed `data_size` as a pointer to the load function to get the right size of the PNG, and changed the `raw_pixel_data` to not pass in the pointer (since it is a pointer already...) It works.